# Encapsulating AFRequestOperationManager with a class and make it available app wide

Tags: objective-c, ios5, afnetworking-2

I am new to Obj C (rubyist here!) so I'm not sure how to go about this. So we use AFNetworking in our app which communicates to our server via a JSON API. Looking at the code right now, there is much repetition, and based on my background, I have a penchant for not being repetitive so we're aiming to refactor this into just one class. The best would be to include it app-wide so we can just access a variable or a method whenever we want to pull something from the server.

Anyway, what we have now is something to this effect:

```
AFHTTPRequestManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:'some@email.com' forHTTPHeaderField:@"EMAIL"
...

[manager GET:url parameters:parameters success:^ (AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
   // do most of the stuff here
} failure: ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
   NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}
```

that's the basic functionality of the method we want to try to make. Most of our API calls (in different custom controllers) are using this pattern. I was thinking, maybe we can pull it out of all the controllers and make it into a class with a method like `getResponseObject` or something because basically that's the only thing we need - a responseObject of the JSON returned by the server.

Also, we are planning to make it available to the whole app, since most of the app are just API calls to the server. Right now we have sort-of encapsulated it into a custom class - but I think if I understand it, every time we do an API call, that class will be created/allocated? Is it advisable to just create that single instance of a class in AppDelegate so it can be available at any time?

*EDIT*

we are trying to encapsulate these methods: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.m#L114-L182 into just one method that takes in the request type as a string (GET, PUT, POST etc).

Answer (score 1):

I have an ApiConnection object that encapsulates this kind of functionality, then each of my elements that needs network connectivity uses that. You should be fine the way you have it set up now with it be allocated each time you need the connection. If you wanted, and some people hate this, you could create it as a singleton and then you would only create the instance on the first usage. I expect there to be a lot of "No don't use singletons" response.

Comment: do you have a method that encapsulates each of these methods? because theres also a method for PUT, POST etc and i'd hate to create a method for each

Comment: I have a generic method

- (void)serviceProcessWithUrl:(NSString *)endPoint httpMethod:(NSString *)httpMethod dataToSend:(NSDictionary *)dataToSend completionHandler:(void(^)(NSError *error, NSDictionary *dataReturned))completionHandler


This handles any kind of REST request that I might want to make. The caller fills in the endpoint, httpMethod and optional dataToSend (for posts)

Comment: can you please add it to your answer? or a link to a gist? I'd like to take a look how you handle "choosing" which method to use (depending on the request type). right now we have a HUGE if-else if statement that is still mighty redundant

Comment: What are you wanting to see, the implementation of that method or how I call it?

Comment: just a general implementation? it would greatly help to see how to implement something that encapsulates all those methods

Comment: ohhhh, so you were using the standard methods. i was referring to the AFNetworking methods, since they have separate methods to encapsulate those.

was referring to these lines: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/AFHTTPRequestOperationManager.m#L114-L182

Comment: You could probably still do something similar with what I did, you would just call the specific method based on the request type. Also ask yourself is the AFNetworking stack making things easier? If you are doing basic get, posts, you might not need all that it offers.